# Flash not even requesting crossdomain.xml

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml

I have a **swf** hosted at `a.domain.com`:

- Embed the player on `a.domain.com`: **Flash player loads, sends loaded callback, have camera access**
- Embed the player on `b.domain.com`: **Flash player loads, no javascript callbacks, no camera access**

My `a.domain.com/crossdomain.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*.domain.com" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.domain.com" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Problem is, the `crossdomain.xml` file is never requested when embedded on a different subdomain.

What in the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you maybe got a security error, to verify that, try your swf using a flash player debug version that you can download here :  [Adobe.com : Flash Player Downloads](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

And to avoid that error, you can try to use this :

- In your ActionScript code : `Security.allowDomain('*');`
- In your swf object HTML embed code : `<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure our dev never had any type of `Security` based code implemented, so we added that in and also changed the script access to `always`, which I didn't even know to look for. Thanks for you help!