# Action Script 3 in Flash CS4. Loop Movie and open

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops

I would like to loop my movie 3 times and open a local .html file in flash using action script 3. If I added a button I know how to do that but not just loop and open?

Thanks

Mthappy

Comment: Your local html will be opened in the browser ?

Comment: Yes basically the .swf file will be viewed within an .html page then run and open a different .html page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can create a counter in the 1st frame of your movieclip and at the last one you have just to increment it until 3, then you can open your html page (link) using `navigateToURL`.

**1st frame :**

```
// we create our counter var only if it didn't already exist (null)
if(!counter){   

    var counter:int = 0;

}
```

**last frame :**

```
counter ++;

if(counter == 3){

    navigateToURL(new URLRequest('page.html'), '_blank');

}
```

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thats is great it loops but does not open the new HTML when viewed in a browser. The .swf is embedded within the HTML? Any ideas?

Comment: @mthappy0 I think that you have a security issue, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514896/flash-not-even-requesting-crossdomain-xml/27539471#27539471).